# Screen shot of C# code file

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I want to take a screen shot of full code from visual studio single file.
is it possible?

if yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need a screenshot of the code?

Comment: Do you mean that you want hidden code under screen client, under scroll bar ?

Answer (score 2):

print to something like a PDF writer? or 'Microsoft Office Document Image Writer'?

Think that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

> 1. File
> 2. Print
> 3. Select Printer Name as Microsoft XPS Document Writer
> 4. Press OK

Answer (score 2):

**To support colors**, you can paste the code into an enormous RichTextBox (or regular-sized with NumericUpDowns to control width and height) and have a button that will do:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(this.richTextBox1.Width, this.richTextBox1.Height);
this.richTextBox1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bitmap.Size));
bitmap.Save("code.bmp");
```

Legacy (doesn't support colors):

```
var allCode = "...copy all of the code into here";
var font = new Font("Arial", 13);
SizeF size;

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
{
    size = g.MeasureString(allCode, font);
}

var bitmap = new Bitmap((int)size.Width + 20, (int)size.Height + 20);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.DrawString(allCode, font, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}

bitmap.Save("code.bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Bitmap BmpScreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
Graphics ScreenShot = Graphics.FromImage(BmpScreen);
ScreenShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
string file = "C:\\test.jpg";
BmpScreen.Save(file, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

is necessary: `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: Sure, the first line is to get the screen width and height in a Bitmap Object. After, define the dir for your image.